# A Slashy Dashy Spiral

Tags: code-golf, string, ascii-art, geometry, integer

Given a positive integer N, output the innermost N×N square of an ASCII art spiral made of `-|/\` that spirals clockwise inward.

The `-` is used for horizontal portions, `|` for vertical portions, and `/` and `\` for corners. The first character is `-` and the spiral proceeds left and down.

Specifically, when N is 1 the output is:

```
-
```

When N is 2 the output is:

```
/-
\-
```

When N is 3 the output is:

```
--\
/-|
\-/
```

When N is 4 the output is:

```
 /--\
 |/-|
 |\-/
 \---
```

Note how every output is a square of N by N characters.

The pattern continues in the same way:

```
N=1
-

N=2
/-
\-

N=3
--\
/-|
\-/

N=4
/--\
|/-|
|\-/
\---

N=5
----\
/--\|
|/-||
|\-/|
\---/

N=6
/----\
|/--\|
||/-||
||\-/|
|\---/
\-----

N=7
------\
/----\|
|/--\||
||/-|||
||\-/||
|\---/|
\-----/

N=8
/------\
|/----\|
||/--\||
|||/-|||
|||\-/||
||\---/|
|\-----/
\-------

etc.
```

The shortest code in bytes wins.

Answer (score 6):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), <s>17</s> 16 bytes:

```
↶⁴-Ｆ⊖Ｎ«↶²/ι↶²\-ι
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z8gsyy/xCc1rUTDRNOaK6AoM69EQ0lXCchOyy9S0HBJTS5KzU3NK0lN0fDMKygt8SvNTUot0tDU1FSo5uJE6DYC6uCEatdXQnAywUysymJidNEU1v7/b/pft@y/bnEOAA) Link is to verbose version of code.

```
↷²-¶Ｆ⊖Ｎ«/ι↶²\-ι↶
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z8gsyy/JCgzPaNEw0jTmiugKDOvRENJNyZPCchLyy9S0HBJTS5KzU3NK0lN0fDMKygt8SvNTUot0tDU1FSo5uKE6tAHqYdyMsFMkME@qWkQc2HKYmJ0cSsE8mr//zf9r1v2X7c4BwA) Link is to verbose version of code.

Edit: Saved 1 byte thanks to @icrieverytim.

Comment: Aw shoot, I got ninja'd. ;-; Anyways, [16 bytes](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z8gsyy/xCc1rUTDRNOaK6AoM69EQ0lXCchOyy9S0NDV9cwrKC3xK81NSi3S0NRUqObiRGgxAirjhOrRV0JwMsFMrMpiYnTRFNb@/2/6X7fsv25xDgA "Charcoal – Try It Online").

Comment: @icrieverytim Oh, I forgot about Decremented, it's too new.

Comment: Neil are you the creator of Charcoal?

Comment: @Jonah [ASCII-only](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/39244/ascii-only), along with [DLosc](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/16766/dlosc), created Charcoal.

Answer (score 4):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>148</s> 134 bytes

```python
f=lambda n,J=''.join:n<2and['-']or n%2and['-'*~-n+'\\']+map(J,zip(f(n-1),'|'*(n-2)+'/'))or map(J,zip('/'+'|'*n,f(n-1)))+['\\'+'-'*~-n]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RY7BDoIwDIbP7il2MV3Z0DD1QuTKgVcADjNIwEhZCBeN8dXnFiBevrR///6tfc3dSNq5Nnua4dYYTqrIAA6PsaeUrtpQU0IM9Thx2m9d9I1JQlVBLQdjRaHevRWtoDhBBR@IfKVRwhEQ/d7f4hUZ5qQWM6IsQ4xcM2vX3FueC8KU7ezU08xpK6Ci5atwCHGVGctFgh464BRwDrggcz8)